# How can I register external component dynamically without any modification of parent(main) Project in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a primary project named "ProjectMain." Additionally, I am working on a separate project, which will serve as an add-on to ProjectMain, let's call it "MyComponent."

I'm planning to develop MyComponent as a library. My question is: can I dynamically import MyComponent into the ProjectMain app without needing to modify any of the existing MainProject code? In essence, I want to load MyComponent dynamically.

If I load the JavaScript in the Document Object Model (DOM), I should be able to use it. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <script type=“text/javascript” src=“my-component.js”></script>
       //if this loaded then i will load the component in the ProjectMain.

    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="app"></div>       
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider explaining your case further, your possible options depend on the specifics. This requirement doesn't add up, as there's no <my-component> in main app and adding it would require to modify its code

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to import your library and have dynamic changes when there is new code in your library you can use **npm link**

So at your library:
`Npm link`
And in your main project
`Npm link <Your Library Name>`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy about a Vue component, it is just a plain javascript object with a name (so that you can refer to in your use-site template).

As long as you register "MyComponent" globally with a name, say "X" (that can happen at any time I believe), in your template you can simply do a dynamic component resolution of "X" (that will be the default behavior if you do not import the component statically).

Or if you do not want to assume any name binding for the "MyComponent" in your "ProjectMain", you can simply use dynamic component: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

The `:is` property does not have be a name (which will trigger component resolution), it can be the component object (which can be fed into the app through provide/inject)